# SQLAlchemy: Group Query Results from two columns by a mutual Foreign Key

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

### What I am trying to do:

I've got 3 tables in a Postgres DB.

```
user
-----------------------
user_id   name      age  
-----------------------
001       Alice     25
002       Bob       32
003       Colin     31
004       Danny     40
```

```
laundry_task
-----------------------------
task_id   user_id   completed  
-----------------------------
101       001       true
102       003       false
103       001       true
```

```
cooking_task
-----------------------------
task_id   user_id   completed  
-----------------------------
201       001       true
202       002       true
203       003       false
```

I need SQLAlchemy to return me a list of tuples, such that:
`[(001, 2, 1), (002, 0, 1)]`
where tuples consist of:
0) **user_id**
1) **number_of_times_laundry_task_completed**
2) **number_of_times_cooking_task_completed**

**OR**
`[(001, 3), (002, 1)]`
where tuples consist of:
0) **user_id**
1) **sum_of_times_boths_tasks_completed**

**I need it in one query.**  (subqueries are okay)

If there are no tasks assigned in 1 of the tables, `completed` count should be set to 0. If there are no tasks assigned in both tables, the tuple should either look like `(004, 0, 0)` (or `(004, 0)`) or not be on the list at all.

### What it looks like in 2 queries:

```
laundry_tasks = (
    session.query(LaundryTask.user_id, func.count(LaundryTask.completed))
           .filter(LaundryTask.completed == True)
           .group_by(LaundryTask.user_id)
           .all()
) # Results in [(001, 2)]


cooking_tasks = (
    session.query(CookingTask.user_id, func.count(CookingTask.completed))
           .filter(CookingTask.completed == True)
           .group_by(CookingTask.user_id)
           .all()
) # Results in [(001, 1), (002, 1)]

# Add some Python parsing to merge two lists of tuples into the needed format...
```

### What I tried and kinda worked (but not really):

**Subqueries:**

```
laundry_tasks_query = (
    select([LaundryTask.user_id, func.count(LaundryTask.completed)])
    .where(LaundryTask.completed == True)
    .group_by(LaundryTask.user_id)
)

cooking_tasks_query = (
    select([CookingTask.user_id, func.count(CookingTask.completed)])
    .where(CookingTask.completed == True)
    .group_by(CookingTask.user_id)
)

final_query = laundry_tasks_query.union(cooking_tasks_query).alias('completed_tasks')
completed_tasks = session.query(final_query).all()
```

Results in: `completed_tasks = [(001, 2), (001, 1), (002, 1)]`
Not sure if there's a way to `group_by` on a `union` before query execution, all my attempts ended up in `Exception`s.

### What I tried and didn't work:

Stuffing everything into one query.

```
completed_tasks = (
    session.query(
         User.user_id, func.count(LaundryTask.completed), func.count(CookingTask.completed)
    )
    .filter(LaundryTask.completed == True)
    .filter(CookingTask.completed == True)
    .group_by(User.user_id)
    .all()
)
```

I know, naive and, as expected, returns some nonsense aka `[(001, magic_number, magic_number), (002, magic_number, magic_number), (003, magic_number, magic_number), (004, magic_number, magic_number)]`, where `magic_number` is the same integer.

If there are any other ways to achieve the output I need, I am more than open to suggestions. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you have to supply like

`group_by(A.user_id, B.user_id)`

Comment: @ChitrankDixit could you elaborate, what query should I put that in?

Comment: you can try in your code, 

`completed_tasks = (
    session.query(
         User.user_id, func.count(LaundryTask.completed), func.count(CookingTask.completed)
    )
    .filter(LaundryTask.completed == True)
    .filter(CookingTask.completed == True)
    .group_by(LaundryTask.user_id, CookingTask.user_id)
    .all()
)`

Comment: Let me know if above solution works for you

Comment: @ChitrankDixit thanks for the suggestion, but I already tried that. It throws an Exception: `column "user.user_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate`. If I also add `User.user_id` into the `group_by()`, it returns bollocks data.